# Assign an individual checkbox value as an array

Tags: php, checkbox

Is there a way of assigning the value of a checkbox as an array.

I have a load of checkboxes, one of which is an all option. I would like to set the value of this to an array?

I have tried creating an array of ints (ids) from an array of my objects using a simple loop and then using print_r in the value (I know this is a bit ugly and I can see why this wouldn't work but can't seem to find the correct syntax).

```
$arrAllID = array();
foreach ($AvailableGroups as $objASRDCallBackGroup)
{
    $arrAllID[] = $objASRDCallBackGroup->m_iGroupID;
}

<input id="group-name" value="<?php print_r($arrAllID) ?>" name="SelectedGroups[]" type="checkbox">All
```

Also I could design around this and do the retrieval of the collection when the form is posted by checking if all was selected or something but I would really like to know how you can do this now..

Any help greatly received.

Thanks

Comment: You should just give it a `name="allChecked"` and then check it in your post script form `if(isset($_POST['allChecked'])){}`

Comment: Yes this is one way but I want to avoid as it couples the two files together, i.e. changing from allChecked to allGroups enforces a change in two places. If this is unavoidable then I will go with this. Thanks for your input though, much appreciated!

Comment: I don't really understand why you have to put all that ids in the value... They won't be usefull for the post script. If you want to check all the checkboxes by clicking on this one, go for a javascript solution.

Comment: Okay I just wanted it to get sent as an array of values which I could use the other side but I will work around it as I think you guys are right it is probably not the right approach anyway. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the HTML5 data attribute to store your array of values.  I'm not very familiar with PHP, but the data attribute will render on the client, and if this checkbox is clicked, you can loop through the array in the data attribute and do whatever you need to send data back to the server.

```
<input id="group-name" data-allid="<?php print_r($arrAllID) ?>" name="SelectedGroups[]" type="checkbox">All

function someClickHandler() {
     var chkGroupName = document.getElementById('group-name');
     var allIds = chkGroupName.attr('data-allid');
    // do what you need with the array of ids.
}
```

Comment: Hi this is a good solution I will look into doing something similar or change my design to something more suitable.. Thanks